# How can text (of all formats) be indented?

Tags: support

I refer to https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/20319/8712, but it uses the grey code format. How can one indent in general, including bolded, italicised, sub/super-scripted texts?

Comment: An HTML `&nbsp;` can do this (but snailplane's ` ` solution below is more elegant, I think).

Answer (score 7):

if you really need to
　then you can always use
　　this 　 space character
　　　just copy and paste it
　　　　from this answer
　　　　　into your own posts
　　　　　　and put a pair of spaces
　　　　　　　at the end of a line
　　　　　　　　or type `<br/>`
　　　　　　　　　if you want to insert
　　　　　　　　　　a newline
　　　　　　　　　though
　　　　　　　　keep in mind
　　　　　　　ell isnt a place
　　　　　　for poetry
　　　　　crazy formatting
　　　　or eccentric style
　　　you probably want
　　to format stuff
　like everyone else
at least i do

Comment: You totally pwn'd me. +1

Comment: The two spaces at the end of the line are preferable to BR I think.  The BR doesn't always render out (or maybe it's just easy to typo). I've edited out a number of them from questions that showed up in the browser I was using.

Comment: Helpful, and delightful. Very Jabberwockyish!

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest using nested blockquotes, like this:

> Aaaa aa aaaa aaaaaaa.
>
> > Bbb b bbbbbb bb bbbb bbbb!
>
> C cccccccccc, ccc cc'c ccc cccc ccccccccccc.
>
> > Ddd d dddddd dd dddd dddd.
> > <sub>Source: Eeeeeee eeeeeeeeee eee eeeeeeee.</sub>

Source:

```
>Aaaa aa aaaa aaaaaaa.
>>Bbb b bbbbbb bb bbbb bbbb!

>C cccccccccc, ccc cc'c ccc cccc ccccccccccc.
>>Ddd d dddddd dd dddd dddd.  
>><sub>Source: Eeeeeee eeeeeeeeee eee eeeeeeee.</sub>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.

The three places to look for your formatting options on SE are:

1. The [help center entry for formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)  and its [advanced editing counterpart](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).
2. The [whitelist of supported HTML tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909) on MSE.
3. The official [Markdown syntax reference](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) page.

Nothing on those pages suggests, to me, that arbitrary indentation is permitted.

Of course, there may be a sneaky, if imperfect, way to simulate indentation using the formatting tools provided, like nested lists, preformatted blocks of spaces at the beginning of every line, use of fancy Unicode spacers plus`<br/>`, etc.